# Datetime issue in Python - Always shows me the same time

Tags: python, selenium, datetime, python-datetime

I am busy with a small project in python, I want help with troubleshooting if you want, If not, please assist with helping me figure out why every time the datetime gets logged, it only shows the time that the script was first run, and not the real local time?

See Code Below:

```
import datetime

Current_Time = datetime.datetime.now()
TimeFormat = Current_Time.strftime("%d %b %Y " + "at " + "%H:%M")
DayFormat = Current_Time.strftime("%d %b %Y ")

def Login_Report():
  f= open("LoginReport.txt","w+")
  f.write('Login Report For: ' + DayFormat + "\n\n")

#Create login report
Login_Report()
```

The above will give me the result of the login report only showing the time that I ran the script the first time.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that demonstrated the issue!

Comment: Question edited. The extract is now a small example of what happens, the code is correct in the sense of when I run the code for only the datetime part, it works, only when its part of the schedule in the previous extract it gives me the time that the script was run initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating the time every time you are logging.

```
import datetime

def Login_Report():
  Current_Time = datetime.datetime.now()
  TimeFormat = Current_Time.strftime("%d %b %Y " + "at " + "%H:%M")
  DayFormat = Current_Time.strftime("%d %b %Y ")
  f= open("LoginReport.txt","w+")
  f.write('Login Report For: ' + DayFormat + "\n\n")

#Create login report
Login_Report()
```

Comment: I will give this a try, thank you for the help!

Comment: I tried it, and it worked very well, thank you for the help once again.

Comment: You can use `logging` module to write the line to file when user logs in instead of opening and writing to file everytime.